# Cadvisor support ELK stack

Tags: go, docker, elastic-stack, cadvisor

ELK stack is heavily used, but cAdvisor only support influxdb. So I want to implement a log stash forward drive base on Lumberjack Protocol.

I think cAdvisor could be able to forward metrics data to LogStash.

So I am planning to work on this.But I really do not know how to begin coding.

https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/634

Answer (score 0):

I already implement store metrics data in ElasticSearch.

Please see https://github.com/google/cadvisor/pull/875